# How can repetitive rows of data be collected in a single row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset that contains the NBA Player's average statistics per game. Some player's statistics are repeated because of they've been in different teams in season.

For example:

```
      Player       Pos  Age Tm    G     GS   MP      FG
8   Jarrett Allen   C   22  TOT  28     10  26.2     4.4
9   Jarrett Allen   C   22  BRK  12     5   26.7     3.7
10  Jarrett Allen   C   22  CLE  16     5   25.9     4.9
```

I want to average Jarrett Allen's stats and put them into a single row. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try groupby?

Comment: I'm a beginner sir, Idk how to do it. Can you send me some sources about this please?

Comment: The syntax is: df.groupby([ <list of columns to keep> ]).mean(). Added an example in answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want to average all those rows? Mathematically it doesn't make sense to average all those rows since a) the `"TOT"` row is already his stats averaged of all the teams he's played for for the season, b) you'd be taking an average of an average in `MP` and `FG`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to get the mean. For the non numeric columns, let's take the first value:

```py
df.groupby('Player').agg({k: 'mean' if v in ('int64', 'float64') else 'first'
                          for k,v in df.dtypes[1:].items()})
```

output:

```
              Pos  Age   Tm          G        GS         MP        FG
Player                                                               
Jarrett Allen   C   22  TOT  18.666667  6.666667  26.266667  4.333333
```

NB. content of the dictionary comprehension:

```
{'Pos': 'first',
 'Age': 'mean',
 'Tm': 'first',
 'G': 'mean',
 'GS': 'mean',
 'MP': 'mean',
 'FG': 'mean'}
```

Comment: Excuse me, can i ask this code's explanation please? What's happening inside of "agg" ? Or can you send me links about this subject?

Comment: `agg` aggregates the values with functions. Here I used a dictionary to tell it which aggregate to compute per column (mean or first). I added a link to the doc in the answer. The dictionary is computed using the columns type. If numeric (int/float) we aggregate with 'mean', else we take the first value. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: If one wants to use the same methods but specifying what to do in each column, one can do the following `df = df.groupby('Player').agg({'Pos': 'first', 'Age': 'mean', 'Tm': 'first', 'G': 'mean', 'GS': 'mean', 'MP': 'mean', 'FG': 'mean'})`.

Answer (score 11):

```
x = [['a', 12, 5],['a', 12, 7], ['b', 15, 10],['b', 15, 12],['c', 20, 1]]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['name', 'age', 'score'])
print(df)
print('-----------')

df2 = df.groupby(['name', 'age']).mean()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  name  age  score
0    a   12      5
1    a   12      7
2    b   15     10
3    b   15     12
4    c   20      1
-----------
          score
name age       
a    12       6
b    15      11
c    20       1
```

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**

If one considers the dataframe that OP shares in the question `df` the following will do the work

```
df_new = df.groupby('Player').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(x.dtype) else x.mean())

[Out]:
              Pos   Age   Tm          G        GS         MP        FG
Player                                                                
Jarrett Allen   C  22.0  TOT  18.666667  6.666667  26.266667  4.333333
```

This one uses:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by the `Player` column
- [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) to aggregate the values based on a custom made lambda function.
- [`pandas.api.types.is_string_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_string_dtype.html) to check if a column is of string type ([see here how the method is implemented](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py#L545-L583))

Let's test it with a new dataframe, `df2`, with more elements in the `Player` column.

```
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['John Collins', 'John Collins', 'John Collins', 'Trae Young', 'Trae Young', 'Clint Capela', 'Jarrett Allen', 'Jarrett Allen', 'Jarrett Allen'],
                    'Pos': ['PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PG', 'PG', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                    'Age': np.random.randint(0, 100, 9),
                    'Tm': ['ATL', 'ATL', 'ATL', 'ATL', 'ATL', 'ATL', 'TOT', 'BRK', 'CLE'],
                    'G': np.random.randint(0, 100, 9),
                    'GS': np.random.randint(0, 100, 9),
                    'MP': np.random.uniform(0, 100, 9),
                    'FG': np.random.uniform(0, 100, 9)})

[Out]:
          Player Pos  Age   Tm   G  GS         MP         FG
0   John Collins  PF   71  ATL  75  39  16.123225  77.949756
1   John Collins  PF   60  ATL  49  49  30.308092  24.788401
2   John Collins  PF   52  ATL  33  92  11.087317  58.488575
3     Trae Young  PG   72  ATL  20  91  62.862313  60.169282
4     Trae Young  PG   85  ATL  61  77  30.248551  85.169038
5   Clint Capela   C   73  ATL   5  67  45.817690  21.966777
6  Jarrett Allen   C   23  TOT  60  51  93.076624  34.160823
7  Jarrett Allen   C   12  BRK   2  77  74.318568  78.755869
8  Jarrett Allen   C   44  CLE  82  81   7.375631  40.930844
```

If one tests the operation on `df2`, one will get the following

```
df_new2 = df2.groupby('Player').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(x.dtype) else x.mean())

[Out]:
              Pos        Age   Tm          G         GS         MP         FG
Player                                                                       
Clint Capela    C  95.000000  ATL  30.000000  98.000000  46.476398  17.987104
Jarrett Allen   C  60.000000  TOT  48.666667  19.333333  70.050540  33.572896
John Collins   PF  74.333333  ATL  50.333333  52.666667  78.181457  78.152235
Trae Young     PG  57.500000  ATL  44.500000  47.500000  46.602543  53.835455
```

---

**Option 2**

Depending on the desired output, assuming that one only wants to group by player (independently of `Age` or `Tm`), a simpler solution would be to just group by and pass `.mean()` as follows

```
df_new3 = df.groupby('Player').mean()

[Out]:

                Age          G        GS         MP        FG
Player                                                       
Jarrett Allen  22.0  18.666667  6.666667  26.266667  4.333333
```

**Notes**:

- The output of this previous operation won't display non-numerical columns (apart from the Player name).