# Pandas: How to sum the values of a column according to a criteria without grouping or adding the others

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which simplified looks like this

```
id  surface longitude latitude othercolumns
1   20      5.878     46.943   ...
1   15      5.88      46.7     ...
1   25      5.5       47       ...
2   30      9.6       40.2     ...
3   10      4.7       36       ...
3   25      3.8       41       ...
```

I read several posts advising groupby but in this case, to the best of my knowledge, it doesn't see to be adapted as it seems that only the variables grouped would be kept, and I need the other columns as well.

On advise I looked as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792897/how-can-repetitive-rows-of-data-be-collected-in-a-single-row-in-pandas), but the formula :

```
df.groupby('Player').agg({k: 'mean' if v in ('int64', 'float64') else 'first'
                      for k,v in df.dtypes[1:].items()})
```

Seems (if I understand it correctly) to apply the calculation to all numeric fields, which would not make sense to sum geographic coordinates.

As a consequence I thought maybe by aiming at having:

(A)

```
id  surface longitude latitude othercolumns
1   60      5.878     46.943   ...
1   60      5.88      46.7     ...
1   60      5.5       47       ...
2   30      9.6       40.2     ...
3   35      4.7       36       ...
3   35      3.8       41       ...
```

(ex: 60 for the sum of 20 + 15 + 25 in the case of id 1)

Then applying df.drop_duplicates() so I can retain something like
(B)

```
id  surface longitude latitude othercolumns
1   60      5.878     46.943   ...
2   30      9.6       40.2     ...
3   35      4.7       36       ...
```

However I don't know how to manage to get to (A), I hope I'm explaining this issue with clarity as I don't have the impression that I saw this brought out before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get to your (A) datframe example by using 'transform' which transforms the grouped by operation back to the original dataframe.

Something like

```
df['surface']=df.groupby('id')['surface'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this is exactly what I was looking for ! It changes the values in surface while leaving the rest of the dataframe unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a list of `numeric_cols` with list comprehension
2. conditionally `.agg` the data with dictionary comprehension according to the dtype.

   ```
   numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns[1:] if df[col].dtype == 'int' or 'float' ]
   (df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
    .agg({f'{col}' : 'sum' 
          if df[col].dtype == 'int' 
          else 'first' 
          for col in numeric_cols}))
   Out[1]: 
      id  surface  longitude  latitude
   0   1       60      5.878    46.943
   1   2       30      9.600    40.200
   2   3       35      4.700    36.000
   ```

You could also do this by column name:

```
numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns[1:] if df[col].dtype == 'int' or 'float' ]
(df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
 .agg({f'{col}' : 'first' if col == 'latitude' or 'longitude'
   else 'sum' 
   for col in numeric_cols}))
```

Comment: Thank you David for your reply, this formula is great but it sums the longitude and latitude which is what I am trying to avoid (otherwise it moves the location to somewhere else in the world !) 
Restricting it to numerical columns is unfortunately not the way to go as longitude and latide needs to be float.
In addition would this formula keep the other columns (such as string columns?)
Actually I would look to a kind of Excel's SumIf formula for Pandas, but I'm not sure it exists though.

Comment: @Frejac I actually updated my answer. Also, rather than `dtype` you could do the condition based on specific column names.

Comment: @Frejac updated my answer again for a second solution

Comment: Thank you David, your formulas are impressive. The second one seemed to work pretty well, the only thing that was missing was that numeric_cols was generated as a list.