# pandas join rows by column values and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe df containing several columns, e.g.:

| COL 1 | COL 2 | COL3 | OTHER COLUMNS... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | ... |
| H | A | D | ... |
| A | B | C | ... |
| J | A | D | ... |
| A | A | C | ... |
| A | A | D | ... |

I want to:

1. join rows with the same COL1 and COL2 values
2. sum values in COL3 (Don't worry for the rest of columns, they will be the same if COL1 and COL2 are equal)

That is that the previous table will become:

| COL 1 | COL 2 | COL3 | OTHER COLUMNS... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C,C | ... |
| H | A | D | ... |
| J | A | D | ... |
| A | A | C,D | ... |

I know how to do the join and sum by applying:

```
df.groupby(['COL1','COL2'])['COL3'].apply(lambda x:','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

which gives me a table with COL1, COL2 and COL3, but then I lose the other columns. Since after grouping and joining the new dataframe has a different amount of rows than the original, I don't know who to map with the previous one. Any idea?

Comment: Define a dictionary with all column names and `'first'` or another default aggregation method, then use `agg` in place of apply

Comment: Check the duplicate link for [details on the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792960/16343464) and let me know if you need help