# How to find the average based on the value of another column. Python/Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, data-science

I want to find the average of my column'Preheat_To_Pour_Time' based on the values of the column `Rampmelt_Active`. Column `Rampmelt_Active` values are either a 1 or a 0 based on if it's active. I can't figure out how to use the values I get from `.value_counts()` if I even need them.

I have tried using `.value_counts()` on `Rampmelt_Active` to get me the count I need to use in my division. As well as the .mean() method. However, this only gives me one value instead of the average of the 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add a groupby() element (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). However, without a minimal reproducible example it is hard to tell (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792897/how-can-repetitive-rows-of-data-be-collected-in-a-single-row-in-pandas