# Pandas groupby is removing columns unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to Pandas and I'm trying to figure something out here. I have the following code:

```
logger.info(f"There are {mydf.shape[0]} rows in the subset dataframe")
logger.info(f"before groupby mydf is: {mydf.head(25)}")
mydf = mydf.groupby([Customer_ID, Customer_Name]).agg("sum").reset_index()
logger.info(f"after groupby mydf is: {mydf.head(25)}")
logger.info(f"Now there are {mydf.shape[0]} rows in the subset dataframe")
```

When I run this, the log output I'm seeing is:

```
There are 36905 rows in the subset dataframe
before groupby mydf is:    Customer ID  Customer Name  ...  Balance Summary Info      EBITDA
after groupby mydf is:    Customer ID  Customer Name  Total Invoice Amount ($)  Revenue         EBITDA
Now there are 66 rows in the subset dataframe
```

Why is my `Balance Summary Info` column going missing after the `groupby`, and what do I have to do to keep it in there (so that its in the final `mydf` dataframe)?

Comment: They're not of numeric type so not included by `sum` function. To confirm, do `mydf.dtypes`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang (+1) how could I print that in my logger statements to confirm? Would `logger.info(f"dtypes = {mydf.dtypes}")` work?

Comment: Yes, assuming your `logger` logs like Python vanilla `print` does.

Comment: You might be interested in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68792897/16343464)

Comment: Thanks again @QuangHoang, when I add that log statement and re-run I get: `dtypes = Customer ID                  object`, what does that tell you? I was expected to get data types for _every_ column in my dataframe _not_ just `Customer ID`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, normally you would see dtypes of all columns with `mydf.dtypes. Or maybe, just for the `Balance` column: `logger.info(f'balance dtype: {mydf["balance"].dtype}')` **before** groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because groupby is an aggregation you have to provide a means to aggregate each column of interest. As said if sum is used generally then non-numeric columns will be ignored. Code below shows one way of aggregating non-numeric columns (by putting into a list). I have used numcol to represent a numerical column to be summed.

```
df2 = mydf.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Customer_Name']).agg({'numcol': 'sum', 'Balance Summary Info': lambda x: list(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks @user19077881 (+1) any chance you could elaborate on your solution a wee bit more? Again I'm new to Pandas and there seems to be a little bit of _magic_ in your solution. Specifically: (1) is `numcol` a keyword in Pandas, or could I call it anything? (2) It _seems_ like you are saying: "Sum any numeric columns and store them in a column called `numcol`, and then add a `Balance Summary Info` column thats just a list of the original values, prior to the `groupby`. Is this a correct gist of your solution, or am I way off? Thanks again!

Comment: numcol is just any specific column name because I did not know what column you want to sum. Note that its a dictionary using { } and inside are items formed by `'colname': function_to_use`. So you could have `'numcol1': 'sum', 'numcol2': 'mean'` using whatever column names and functions which are relevant to your application. I wanted to show that non-numbers could be retained by aggregating in a list. Hope this is some use to you.

Comment: Interesting, so currently the code is `mydf.groupby([Customer_ID, Customer_Name]).agg("sum").reset_index()`, if you are unsure of what column I need summed, what is currently being chosen by Pandas in that line of code?

Comment: Is `lambda x: list(x)` necessary? Would just passing `list` do the same thing?

Comment: If you use `agg("sum")` then Pandas will use ALL numeric columns and ignore all others. If you want to do different things with different columns then you need to specify each column and what you want to do with it.

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie Yes, a good point. `list` could be also used directly (without being in quotes) and would in this case have maybe been a simpler example. I made it generic so that any function including user-defined could be used.

Comment: Thanks @user19077881 (+1 again), if you get a chance would you mind seeing my comment up above about printing out the `mydf.dtypes`? The output there doesn't make sense to me, as I have more than just a "Customer ID` column in the dataframe. Thanks for any insight you can lend there!

Comment: Simply use `print(mydf.dtypes)` and it will show a list of each column name and its type such as `int64, float64, object`. The dtype `object` is a 'catch-all' type which includes strings.